# Inserting extra comma while multi upload how to avoid this

Tags: laravel-5

here what i need to do for avoiding extra comma separater while upload the images.it takes one more image while upload the file.i used comma separater for the concatination.

Controller

```
            $filename_new_get = "";
            $count = Input::get('count');
          for($i = 0 ; $i < $count ; $i++)

        {

            $file_more = Input::file('file_more'.$i);

            $file_more_name = $file_more->getClientOriginalName();  

            $move_more_img = explode('.',$file_more_name);

            $filename_new =            $move_more_img[0].str_random(8).".".$move_more_img[1];

            $newdestinationPath = '../assets/categoryimage/';

            $uploadSuccess_new =Input::file('file_more'.$i)->move($newdestinationPath,$filename_new);
            $filename_new_get .= $filename_new.","; 

        }


     $inputs = Input::all();

         $file = Input::file('file');

         $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

         $move_img = explode('.',$filename);

         $filename = $move_img[0].str_random(8).".".$move_img[1];

         $destinationPath = '../assets/categoryimage/';

         $uploadSuccess = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath,$filename);

         $file_name_insert = $filename . ",".$filename_new_get;
      $data=array(
                 'new_category_image'=> $file_name_insert,
                 );
```

Views

```
<div class="col-lg-8" id="img_upload">
                   <input type="file"  id="file0" name="file" style="background:none;width:185px;border:none;">no files
                    <div id="divTxt"></div>
            <p><a onClick="addproductimageFormField(); return false;" style="cursor:pointer;color:#F60;width:84px;" id="add_img_btn" >Add</a></p> 
                   <input type="hidden" id="aid" value="1">
                    <input type="text" id="count" name="count" value="0">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$newFileName = rtrim($file_name_insert, ',');
```

[rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) will remove the last unwanted , from the concatenated string.